# Solving the equation $z=\sum_i \alpha_i \exp(-\|x_i-z\|^2)x_i$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, terminology, operator-theory

For $i=1,\dots,M$ vectors $x_i\in\mathbb{R}^N$ and scalars $\alpha_i$, can you find a vector $z$ satisfying the equation $z=\sum_i \alpha_i \exp(-\|x_i-z\|^2)x_i$?

Any pointers will also be appreciated:

- does such an equation have a name?
- is it discussed systematically in some field of math or physics?
- how many such solutions can you expect to find?

Thanks!

Comment: For some values of the constants the function $f(z)=\sum_i \alpha_i\exp(-||x_i-z||^2)x_i$ will be contractive. The solution of your equation will be the only fixed point of $f$.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla, "the only fixed point of $f$" may still depend on the initial condition $z_0$, no?

Comment: If $f$ is contractive the fixed point is unique, independent of the initial condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously,
$$\lim_{\|z\|\to\infty}\sum_i \alpha_i \exp(-||x_i-z||^2)x_i=0$$
(zero vector) and for $R$ large enough
$$f:B(0,R)\longrightarrow B(0,R).$$
By Brouwer, your equation will have always some solution (a fixed point of $f$).

Comment: So this yields existence of at least one solution, while in your comment you say that for some values of the parameter will be unique?

Comment: Yes. But *maybe* for some values of the parameters $f$ isn't contractive in the whole space but in some subsets.